# Euler's Hypergeometric Transformations

Tags: calculus

it is possible to transform the following hypergeometric function as Euler Transform
$$\left[\, _3F_2\left(\text{a2},\text{b2},k+\frac{1}{2};c,k+2;p\right)\right]$$
Thanks

Comment: I presume that you want p->1/p or p/(1-p) ?  And a2 means 2*a ?

Comment: yes the first part a2 is a2 variable

Comment: I can probably answer but there are several "Euler" transforms: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerTransform.html  or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_transform#Euler_transform or an example of what you have in mind might do.

Comment: IT IS DO NOT FIT FOR THE HYPERGEOMETRIC FUNCTION ABOVE

Comment: Be aware ALL CAPS is often counterproductive/not constructive.  You need to go through the Meijer G-function and then use mpmath for calculations.  Alternately http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/MeijerG/03/01/05/13/ and http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/MeijerG/03/01/03/33/ and https://dlmf.nist.gov/16.19.E1 can provide a direct   closed form; but be aware that there are numerous domain restrictions that have to be accomidated for the G-functions parameters and varaible values.